# Android Emulator keeps crashing after button Press

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

My Android emulator crashes whenever I press keys on the pc keyboard or hit the emulator side buttons. the only part that works is the emulator mobile screen. This doesn't happen to just one device but to all emulators I use. This is really annoying cause whenever I press any key on the keyboard while the emulator screen is active it will instantly crash. But keystrokes won't crush it when text input is active on the emulator screen. The operating system I use is ubuntu but Windows fix is also useful.

I need help from someone who has managed to solve this problem before.

[image: Android emulator]

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure I got this error before too. Whenever I pressed a button, the emulator would just say "Saving State..." and just closes. The only solution I found to fix this was to delete the emulator and create a new one. It's not the most effective solution, but I couldn't find any other solutions.